# Issue with date fetched using 'date' & 'strtotime' function in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am fetch day, month and year separately from date using date function in PHP.
I am passing two dates in this function, one is fromdate and other is todate. 
In case of todate, function is returning appropriate values but in case of fromdate, function is returning 0,1,2 for month,day,year respectively.

Here is the code that i am using in PHP:

```
// here i am passing values for fromdate and todate fetched from POST, these values are proper

$from = $_POST['event_fromdate'];
$to=$_POST['event_todate'];

// here i am fetching month,day & year separately from fromdate , these values are not proper 

$time['month'] = date('m',strtotime($from));
$time['day'] = date('d',strtotime($from));
$time['year'] = date('Y',strtotime($from));

// here i am fetching month,day & year separately from todate , these values are proper

$time1['month'] = date('m',strtotime($to));
$time1['day'] = date('d',strtotime($to));
$time1['year'] = date('Y',strtotime($to));
```

On printing these values one by one, output is:

```
Actual From date: 13-APR-2013
Actual To date  : 14-APR-2013

'From date' fetched from date function:
  month = 0
  day = 1
  year = 2


'To date' fetched from date function:
  month = 04
  day = 14
  year = 2013
```

Here i have tried in all way but not getting why i am getting inappropriate result in case of FROM DATE.

Comment: Looks like you print out the keys, instead of values.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($from)`, right before fetching day, month and year?

Comment: If you change the format of the date does it work properly? Try a test with YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: can you please print the both arrays. print_r($time) and print_r($time1)

Comment: @Kalapana: atleast you should response for the comments. Or else why you are posting you things here?

Comment: Please post reproducible code (set $from to $to to constant values), add var_dump($time) and var_dump($time1) and include output of the dumps. I have tried to reproduce this myself, but it works for me.

Comment: @VinothBabu: sorry for late reply but i was not on my desk, yes i printed these arrays and i got:   for time: 2m and for time1:Array ( [month] => 04 [day] => 14 [year] => 2013 )

Comment: @Uby: string '13-APR-2013' (length=11) on var_dump($from) before fetching subparts

Comment: @KalpanaDixit: You are from?

Comment: @VinothBabu: at this moment i am in gujarat, basically from U.P

Comment: @Kalpana Dixit: Me too India.. :) and from state CSK in IPL, but now in RCB in IPL :) can i have your mail id please?

Comment: @VinothBabu: May i know for what purpose you are asking for email id?

Comment: @KalpanaDixit : Dont get afraid. Thats ur wish. Just i ll ad in my google chat and if i have any doubt i can ask or if you have any doubt you can also ask. Just KT(knowledge Transfer). If you wish give or else ok.. :)

Comment: @VinothBabu: okay not an issue...its kalpanadixit89@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just put it in a DateTime object, you can extract all the values from there, saves you a lot of duplicate code.

```php
$dt_to     = new DateTime($to);
$some_info = array(
  'day'   => $dt_to->format('d'),
  'month' => $dt_to->format('m'),
  'year'  => $dt_to->format('Y')
);
```

It would however be a cleaner solution to just pass the DateTime object to the endpoint where you actually need the days/months/years.